# onWheelCapture vs onWheel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is there any difference between the two? React offers both options and I don't see a huge difference in the way it is triggered.

Here is some code that I was tinkering with

```
// Add page transition functions here too
      onWheelCapture={e=>{
        console.log(e);
      }}
      onWheel={(e)=>{
        console.log(e);
      }}
```

For context, I have been trying to hijack the default scroll behaviour and need to change some states based on the scroll. I just want to know which is better to use and which one is the standard way of going about and the better events.

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events#capture-phase-events